# Extract text in parentheses

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help. I need to extract the text that is in the parenthesis below. How do I do this? Please see the below sample data.

```
Last1, First1 (A000001)
Last2, First2 (A000002)
```

I need to extract

```
A000001
A000002
```

How can I do this with an excel formula? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are those the only parentheses that will appear in your text?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-text-between-parentheses). Also, it could get simpler if we would know more details, like would the extracted part always be of the same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula

```
=MID(D6,FIND("(",D6)+1,FIND(")",D6)-FIND("(",D6)-1)
```

(replace D6 with the actual cell that has your content)

The MID function works to extract text between a initial point until X characters later. With this, we find the position of the first parenthesis with FIND (+1 to ignore it).

Also with FIND, we locate the position of the last parenthesis and subtract the position of the first one to get how many characters MID should look up for after the first "("